# Count occurrences of an entry in a hashmap property of an entity in a list

Tags: jsf, count, hashmap, el

I've a `WorkflowTask` entity with a `Map<String, Object>` property.

```
public class WorkflowTask {
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

The `Map` has an entry `bpm_status` which can have a value of `Not Yet Started`.

I'm displaying a `List<WorkflowTask>` in a data table and checking for this entry like below:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{inboxController.list}" var="task">
    <p:column>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{task.properties.bpm_status eq 'Not Yet Started'}"><b>#{msg.inbox_new_msg}</b>
        </ui:fragment>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I'd like to show a counter with total occurrences of this map entry `bpm_status=Not Yet Started` in the list.

```
<p>Amount of new messages: #{inboxController.list.???}</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question is long winded. All the REST thing and refresh period is irrelevant to the presentation problem. Just create a MCVE with a "hardcoded" model and precisely tell what values exactly you want to present in the view. That part is even not clear, so I cannot edit the question to reduce the noise and boil down the real question.

Comment: Ok, give me some time, I will try to make this post as clear as possible..
p.s. MCVE ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: You're still terribly long winded and vague. After re-reading the question 3 times, I gather that you basically have an `List<Entity>` where `Entity` has a `Map<String, Object>` property, and that you'd like to show total occurrences of the map entry with key `bpm_status` and value `IN_PROGRESS` in the JSF page? Was that your question in one clear paragraph instead of 1000 words and 50 loc?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you r right, just tried to explain it :)

You are almost righ, I need to make count of all `bpm_status` that has value `Not Yet Started`  which means it's a new messgae ( not opened yet).

And to display a count number, of how many un-opened messages there is.

**EDIT** : for example, you open FaceBook, and on left side menu you see `messages  2`   this means in your inbox there is 2 un-opened messages.. so I need same

Comment: And you r right, I could explain it more clearly, maybe.. but that's what happens when you are very junior and have not the best English skills.

Comment: Your English is fine. This has nothing to do with the communication language. This has everything to do with logically thinking. This is independent of the mother tongue. I have updated your question, hopefully youl'll take that as a lesson hint for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EL 3.0, you can use Java8-like [stream and lambda operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el004.htm) in EL expressions without the need for Java8 (works on Java7 already).

Your requirement can be achieved as below:

```
<p>Amount of new messages: #{inboxController.list.stream().filter(task -> task.properties.bpm_status eq 'Not Yet Started').count()}</p>
```

In case you aren't on EL 3.0 yet, then you need to count it in backing bean itself.

```
int notYetStartedCount = 0;

for (WorkflowTask task : list) {
    if ("Not Yet Started".equals(task.getProperties().get("bpm_status"))) {
        notYetStartedCount++;
    } 
}
```

In case you're interested, the Java8 equivalent of above would be:

```
long notYetStartedCount = list.stream().filter(task -> "Not Yet Started".equals(task.getProperties().get("bpm_status"))).count();
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, project team works on JAVA 7, so can't use Lambda's.

Comment: Sorry.. missunderstood it at first. 

And big Thanks for helping me not only find answer for JAVA question but having patience with me :)